# Adding a button at the bottom of a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a better way of adding a button at the bottom of a table view as seen below? The solutions I found involved inserting a button inside the header or footer of an existing section, seems kinda hacky to me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you are looking at is a UITableView.  If you have several entries, then the info for this person would scroll off the screen along with the "Delete" button.  Putting the button in the table footer would allow it to scroll along with the table.  The table footer is outside of any section.

If your view does not have any scrolling or a dynamic sized table view you could just add it to the bottom of the view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The table footer is outside of any section". UITableView does not have any built-in footer AFAIK. Only the cell's section has header/footer

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the button to scroll along with the cells

Comment: UITableView has a property called tableFooterView where you can set it to any UIView.  It is outside of any sections.  It will allow the button to scroll along with the table.

Comment: Ah, just checked the docs, you are right. Let me play around with that

Answer (score 5):

Create a new UIView and set the view to the tableview's footer view and add the button as the subview of the new UIView. Also, set the height for the footer in heightForFooterInSection method.

Something like this in viewDidLoad,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 300, 45)];
    submit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [submit setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[submit setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.56] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [submit setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [submit.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [submit setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 280.0, 44.0)];
    [newView addSubview:submit];

    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:newView];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a toolbar with a delete button? IMHO, it would look "nicer".

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `UIView` and then add a `UIButton` into that so that `UIButton` could not autoresized to fit to width.