# UIViewController and Autolayout subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using Masonry to set the constraints of the subviews.

The view controller is simple.

in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.view addSubview: self.tableView];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.tableView addSubview: self.botBtn];
    [self.botBtn makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.tableView.bottom).with.offset(-20);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.tableView);
    }];
}
```

The frame for the table view is CGRectMake(0,0,screen_width,screen_height),
but the button is outside of the screen and just on the top of the tableview.

I set the tableview frame in it's init method.
The button stays in the mid of the view horizontally so the autolayout seems work, but why it is positioned on the top of the tableview instead of staying on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly well done for using Masonry :D.

To your question, I don't think you're adding the button in the right way, I'm guessing you want to add a button to bottom of the tableview, so when you scroll to the bottom of the tableview you will see your button? If so, just create a UIView with a button and set the tableview's footer view, i.e. `[self.tableView setTableFooterView:newView];` as described in this question, [Adding a button at the bottom of a table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932032/adding-a-button-at-the-bottom-of-a-table-view)

Let me know if this is not what you're actually looking for, good luck.